# event receiver sharepoint online

Tags: events, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, eventreceiver

I have a basic question regarding SharePoint Online.

A list was made in the past. On this list a custom event receiver was attached.

I need to detach the event receiver from the list but I do not know where I can find an overview of all event receivers attached to objects in SharePoint.

This seems to be very basic, but I have searched the web and I can only find how to create and attach, but not how to detach and overview.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never done this myself but I believe that you need to install the SharePoint online tools.

You will then need to do then do some powershell commands to then remove.

```
 # Paths to SDK. Please verify location on your computer. 
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"  
Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"  

# Insert the credentials and the name of the admin site 
$Username="admin@tenant.onmicrosoft.com" 
$AdminPassword=Read-Host -Prompt "Password" -AsSecureString 
$Url="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/teamsitewithlibraries" 
$ListTitle="kriiv" 
$EventReceiverGUID="154d2ca2-8335-464c-9059-214cdcc1c2c1" 

Get-SPOListEventreceivers -Username $Username -AdminPassword $AdminPassword -Url $Url -ListTitle $ListTitle -EventReceiverGUID $EventreceiverGUID
```

I've taken the above code from [this](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/SharePoint-Online-Remove-a-4fb07ced)

Hope this helps

Truez

Answer (score 0):

try the pnp powershell, quite handy.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP-PowerShell/blob/master/Documentation/RemoveSPOEventReceiver.md